# Complex ternary operator in inline Angular template filter

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator, angular-filters

The **is_shared** `filter` below isn't working correctly. The correct value is shown when I render the result of the ternary operation to HTML but for some reason the ng-repeat isn't being affected by it.

```
ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items
     | filter: {name: ctrl.settings.searchText, is_shared: (item.is_shared ? ctrl.settings.showShared : true)}
     | orderBy: (ctrl.settings.order + ctrl.settings.propertyToSortBy)
"
```